# Building a dictionary at runtime in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I am trying to build a simple dictionary at runtime in Swift. I am fairly new to Swift, but experienced in Obj-C (and missing it).

I am gathering some JSON data via a web service and looping through its elements. During this loop I need to build the dictionary. Here is the dictionary I need to generate

```
"gauge": {
    "gaugeID" : "03185"
    "name" : "SOME GAUGE NAME"
    "cfs" : 8410
    "stage" : 7.05
}
```

Since values for `cfs` and `flow` may not be present, I need to add these values to the dictionary conditionally.

I have declared the following dictionary

```
var dictEntry:[String:AnyObject]
```

Then as I loop through the dictionary I need to build each key-value and add it to the `dictEntry` dictionary. Every attempt I've made to do this fails. In Obj-C I could do the following:

```
[entryDict setValue:someValue forKey:@"cfs"];
```

How is this possible in Swift? Thanks!

Comment: What is the type of the source data? `NSData`? If you show me how you are doing the call to the webservice I can describe you the full process to transform that data into a `[String:AnyObject]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
dictEntry["cfs"] = someValue
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Do you get a compiler error? Something else?

Comment: So, your answer turns out to be correct, but the error was in my declaration of dictEntry. Changing the declaration to 
var dictEntry = [String:AnyObject]()
fixed the issue

Comment: Glad to hear that. By the way, in Objective-C you can do much the same: `dictEntry[@"cfs"] = someValue;`, without using the clunky `setValue:forKey:` syntax.